# php read csv data by column

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to recieve data from a .csv. Here the code I have so far:

```
if(($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE){
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){
    }
}
```

But this puts all the data I need in the first entry in the $data array. What I need to do is `$data[1]` and then get all the values from the second column. I've done it before but I can't it to work this time. How do I do it?

**EDIT**

Here is my .csv file structure

```
|  ID  |  Name    |
|------|----------|etc
|  1   |Product 1 |
```

Here's a screenshot of the file https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VnVb.jpg

And with `echo $data[1]` it should return 'Product 1'

Comment: In `$data` you will have the single columns of each line. So please make an example of a little input file and the expected output

Comment: @Rizier123 i've included in the question now. I can't use images yet because my rep is too low

Comment: Works fine for me! Do you get any errors ? What output do you get?

Comment: @Rizier123 when I use `$data[1]` I get 85;13 when I print the variable I see all the data from the file is stored in `$data[0]`

Comment: Then I think you don't show us your **real** csv file structure.  Just make a screenshort of the file, edit your question with an imgur link and someone with enough rep will edit it with the image

Comment: :D This is a excel file (probably `.xlsx`)! This isn't a csv file.

Comment: @Rizier123 it's saved as a .csv ...

Comment: http://imgur.com/oCJMOne

Comment: Could I have the csv file please, or a part, but with the full header and 1 line of datas

Comment: @zlen what do you mean with "with the full header'?

Comment: The name of colums, the head

Comment: @zlen like this? http://imgur.com/2G4SKwG

Comment: In your file data is separated by semicolon, but in your `fgetcsv` call you are splitting data by a comma. Change it to semicolon and it would work.

Comment: @ Jojo : it don't change anything. Hard thing to get results because you have to detect the carriage return

Answer (score 0):

Please be specific to your question. Anyway, these codes will help you to your question.

```
<?php
$csv = array();
// check there are no errors
if($_FILES['csv']['error'] == 0){
    $name = $_FILES['csv']['name'];
    $ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['csv']['name'])));
    $type = $_FILES['csv']['type'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];

    // check the file is a csv
    if($ext === 'csv'){
        if(($handle = fopen($tmpName, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
            // necessary if a large csv file
            set_time_limit(0);

            $row = 0;

            while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
                // number of fields in the csv
                $col_count = count($data);

                // get the values from the csv
                $col1 = $data[0];
                $col2 = $data[1];
                $col3 = $data[2];
                $col4 = $data[2];               
                // inc the row
                $row++;
            }   

            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}

?>
```